# Alias or Redirection from \\Server1\folderA to \\Server2\folderB

Tags: windows, networking, filesystems, fileserver

We currently have a legacy solution (on Windows) where the source code cannot be changed, and it is hard-coded to use paths in a specific location `\\Server1\folderA` for example on really old servers where data-content is stored.

We now have new servers that we want to use instead to hold our data content, but cannot update the hard-coded paths in the legacy solution to use these directly.

Is there anyway to use an alias, or a redirection from one fileserver to another, so that when something tries to get data content from path `\\Server1\folderA` it gets redirected over to `\\Server2\folderB` for example and therefore uses the files on the new server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to my own problem:

Open a Command Prompt with Administrator privileges and use the following command:

```
mklink /d \\Server1\folderA \\Server2\folderB
```